# AccessibilityNodeInfo - send text

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am developing an Android app, where I have to send text to focused `EditText` field of other Applications.

I have done it in `API level 18` and above using `AccessibilityService`, when I find the `EditText`, I paste the data from ClipBoard. Here is the code,

```
public class TestService extends AccessibilityService {

  @Override
  public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
        if (source != null && event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED && event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "TEST DATA");
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
        }
   }
}
```

But, `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE` is available in API level 18 and above.

Can we achieve the same in API Level < 18 ?

I read in some blogs that it can be done using `InputMethodService`, where we create our own keyboard and send text via that soft keyboard. I did not understand much of it...

can someone help me on this.

Comment: Amith, did you figure out how to achieve ACTION_PASTE in API level below 18?

Comment: as of now, there is no way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACTION_PASTE from API 14, but you have to call `AccessibilityRecordCompat` and `AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat` like there:

```
AccessibilityRecordCompat record = AccessibilityEventCompat.asRecord(event);
AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat source = record.getSource();
source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the view that has the current focus:

```
public View getCurrentFocus() {
    return mWindow != null ? mWindow.getCurrentFocus() : null;
}
```

And then setting up the text:

```
editTextObject.setText(CharSequence)
```

Comment: I have to send text to focused EditText field of other Applications. How do i get the activity instance? not possible right..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use AccessibilityNodeInfo even from API 14 and up but ACTION_PASTE you have to use  only from Api Level 18.
Have a look at
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html